# C# - Every 6-digit combination of a list of numbers (Permutations)

Tags: c#, permutation, combinations

I'm looking to generate a list of every possible 6 number combination given an array of numbers.

i.e. myArray = ['23','65','64','21','76',54','86'...]

Output:

23:21:65:83:91

01:64:22:25:67

61:09:26:81...

...

...

Comment: must provide with some work around it

Comment: Can you have duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

There's a really nice library on CodeProject that handles Combinations, Permutations and Variations.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G